# Invocation in ruby without a method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard

In my Guardfile I have this strange method invocation syntax `rspec.spec.("requests/#{m[1]}")`. While this works perfectly I don't understand is what method is actually being called.

Is there a name or term for this syntax?

```
guard :rspec, cmd: "bundle exec rspec" do

  # ...
  watch(rails.controllers) do |m|
    [
      rspec.spec.("routing/#{m[1]}_routing"),
      rspec.spec.("controllers/#{m[1]}_controller"),
      rspec.spec.("requests/#{m[1]}")
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Drenmi, I could not think up a good search phrase. Its a duplicate.

Comment: No problem @max. It took some searching to find because of the peculiar lack of method name. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
foo = "Foo"
foo.("a")
# NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for "Foo":String

routine = Proc.new { |arg| puts "Hello #{arg}!" }
routine.("world")
# Hello world!
```